# How to count the number of rows where three number columns = 0

Tags: excel

I've researched and researched and can't find an Excel statement that will go down all the rows within a range of rows and count the number of rows where three cells = zero.  I've considered the possibility of using an IF statement but can't identify the right syntax.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if you are asking about: 1) counting the number of rows that have  exactly three cells with a 0 numeric value; 2) the number of rows that have 0 numeric value in a particular column; 3) the number of rows that have 0 numeric value in three particular columns; or 4) something else.

Comment: I wish I could attach a picture of the spreadsheet.  Starting at row 4 and continuing to row 75, if the b,c,d columns = 0, counter +1.  Move on to the next row until the specified range of rows is complete.

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: @user3293760 You _can_ attach a picture even if you don't have sufficient reputation. Just upload it on an image host and put the link to the picture in your question. Someone will likely come around and turn the link into an actual picture for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, this will return the number of rows where the Values in Columns B,C, And D have a value of 0 in the same row.

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,0,C:C,0,D:D,0)
```

If you only wanr to count for rows 4:75 you would change the formula to:

```
=COUNTIFS(B4:B75,0,C4:C75,0,D4:D75,0)
```

Comment: This got it.  As usual, I was over-complicating things.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need. To count the number of rows where cells are equal to 0:

```
=COUNTIF(range,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try COUNTIF(Column,0)
Such as COUNTIF(A:A,0)